# sending data from one android device to another android device via server

Tags: android

I am developing an application in which I have to send data from one device to another device via server. I am using soapObject for sending the data.

I am able to send data from the device to server and get back the result from server,but I am not getting how to send data sent from one device to another device via the server.

If anybody knows how to do this, please respond.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The other device (the receiving phone) has to establish a connection with the server.  When the server receives data from the sending device, it can then send the data directly to the receiving device.

Comment: The connections between server and clients will be independent. Then is there any way for the server to know how to send data from one client to another client?